# Firefox Addon: Access Variable in other File

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How can i easy access the variable "test" from main.js?

```
    \my-addon-project
       \data 
         \file.js (var test = "123")
       \lib: 
         \main.js
```

The main question is, how to include the file.js in the main.js. And how do i get the value of the variable "test".

With require? Searched a few hours for this simple question.

Please help me. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok make a jsm file, its real simple, here is an example how to make one called hello world:

see the comments bellow the gist it tells you how to access this jsm in another addon, for example purposes it shows how to do it in scratchpad.

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the add-on sdk. [Here's how to communicate between main.js and content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port).

All the resources you'll ever need can be found in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK). So you should only be searching if what you read there is confusing or incomplete.

Add a comment if you have questions about how to navigate the docs.